# Dictionary of Properties in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a series of 'codes' that I want to refer to properties in my class.  However, when I set the values of the dictionary, the properties aren't updated.  An example below

```
public Foo() {
    this.CodeMap = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    this.CodeMap.Add("stat", this.Status);
    this.CodeMap.Add("ver", this.Version);
}

public int Status { get; set; }

public int Version { get; set; }
```

And the calling code

```
foo.CodeMap["stat"] = 27;
/* foo.Status is not set to 27 */
```

Is there a way to do this in .NET.  I believe the error occurs because the dictionary value isn't an ref value, but I'm not sure the best way to do this.  I saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/10350484/450745 but that is kinda the opposite of what I want.

Comment: you example is missing a lot of detail, assuming you're copying the body of some class, and the foo variable is an instance of that class, what you want to do is box and unbox status and version. read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: What do you expect to happen when someone writes `foo.CodeMap["stat"] = "blah";`?

Comment: I was hoping that the property Status would have been updated like a pointer. Assuming you passed an int and not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you add the Key, "stat", to the `Dictionary` with whatever value Status has when the assignment is made.  When you update that Key's value later, it won't automatically update your property.  You are adding the value of a property *at a point in time* to the `Dictionary`, but not the property itself.

What you want to do isn't possible using a standard `Dictionary`.  You have a couple of options that don't seem terrible though.

**Observable Dictionary**

See this [blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx) and this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621276/c-sharp-check-if-a-dictionary-has-changed-values-in-another-class-through-an-eve).

The general idea is to write a class that inherits from `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `INotifyCollectionChanged`, and `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

This will give you some hooks that you can write event handlers for that could theoretically allow you to update some properties or whatever else you wanted to do.

**Refactor your code**

If you don't like the above, then you could refactor your code slightly.

Consider this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> CodeMap;

    public int Status
    {
        get 
        {
            int status;
            if (int.TryParse(CodeMap["stat"].ToString(), out status))
            {
                return status;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Status has a non-numeric value");
            }
        }
        set 
        { 
            CodeMap["stat"] = value; 
        }
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        CodeMap = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
}
```

Then you could make the same call:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.CodeMap["stat"] = 27;

Console.WriteLine(foo.Status.ToString());  // prints 27
```

Hopefully it's fairly obvious why this works.  Now the property actually references the `Dictionary`.  Be aware that you can't add the initial values the same way as before, as you would get a `KeyNotFoundException` when the getter tries to access that Key.  I see this as a pretty small downside however.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to use an observable dictionary.

Comment: Hi, the blog post link is inaccessible.

Answer (score 3):

For future viewers, in simple cases its enough to use Func'<'T'>'.

```
  public string TestProperty {get; set;}
  public Dictionary<int, Func<string>> dictionary;

  Constructor()
  {
    dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Func<string>>
    {
        {1, ()=>TestProperty }
    }
  }
```

And when use like this:

```
  dictionary[1]() or dictionary[1].Invoke()
```

It returns the actual value of property at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> I believe the error occurs because the dictionary value isn't an ref value,

No it is because you have not set `foo.Status`. `foo.CodeMap` and `foo.Status` are different.

If you want to sync the values, you should do it manually. You can inherit from `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` and override the `Add` method.

like

```
void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
{
   if (key is string && key.Equals("stat"))
   {
      this.stat = (int)value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this response as it would work, but I will be exposing these classes and it wouldn't make sense as a dictionary. People should be able to create them without knowing anything about the dictionary. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary doesn't update the value of previous value property. When you stored `foo.CodeMap["stat"] = 27;` the earlier value of the `foo.CodeMap["stat"]` (which was the value of `Status`) gets overwritten with `27`.

A position identified by a key ("stat" in your case) within a dictionary is a data-store, i.e. `CodeMap["stat"]` is the storage location of your data, not the other way round. Anything you store in this location overwrites previous data.

You should elaborate on your the actual problem that you are trying to solve. Your question isn't clear enough for readers to deduce the actual need/problem.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is given a random string be able to know which property to update. I'm deserializing some data that looks like "stat 200" and there are many different files of data. Each file corresponds to a different class. I want a generic Deserialize<T>() : where T : Data, new(). The deserialize method, upon seeing a code should be able to update a property in T. I have each type of data a subclass of Data which filled in the dictionary. The in the  deserialize method I was doing if(dataFile.CodeMap.ContainsKey(keyReadFromFile)) { dataFile.CodeMap[keyFromDataFile] = dataValue; }

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).
This is sample with one way binding to dictionary:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Properties = new ExpandoObject();
        Status = 0;
        Version = 0;
    }

    public dynamic Properties { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> CodeMap
    {
        get { return Properties; }
    }

    private int _status;
    public int Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            Properties.stat = _status;
        }
    }

    private int _version;
    public int Version
    {
        get { return _version; }
        set
        {
            _version = value;
            Properties.ver = _version;
        }
    }
}
```

using:

```
var foo = new Foo
                {
                    Status = 1,
                    Version = 2
                };

Console.WriteLine(foo.CodeMap["stat"]);
Console.WriteLine(foo.CodeMap["ver"]);
Console.WriteLine(foo.Properties.stat);
Console.WriteLine(foo.Properties.ver);
```